# Possible to use VpnService implementation to capture and send packets?

Tags: android

I'm considering the possibility of using the new android (4.0) VpnService interface to implement simple packet capture and analysis. Does anyone know if it's possible to take the packets you receive in a VpnService implementation and simply write them out to the active/default network device? To receive data, I'd have to be able to read from the network device as well, of course. If it is possible, what APIs can be used to write to the network device(s)?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: @brianestey - I have not myself been able to implement this using VpnService, but there is an [application in the google market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture) that appears to be using this technique. I still don't know how to write the packets out to the network once you've trapped them in your VpnService implementation, but perhaps the author of this app has figured it out.

Comment: Yah, I saw that app and was wondering how they did it.  Have you looked at the ToyVpnService sample provided by Google in the API samples?  They give code for a VpnServer as well as the Android VpnService app.  I am currently trying to figure if that code can be used on the device itself to forward the packets (ie. Android app connects to a locally running VPN server that just proxies packets back and forth)

Comment: This application does this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture

Comment: See this example http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/android-vpn-service/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tPacketCapture creates a second socket to the remote machine to forward the packets.  I have looked at `tPacketCapture` using `adb shell netstat`:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address              Foreign Address            State 
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.126:49828        97.74.42.79:80             ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:5000      :::*                       LISTEN
tcp6       0    522 ::ffff:10.8.0.1:50294      ::ffff:97.74.42.79:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.126:34210 ::ffff:74.125.141.188:5228 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:192.168.1.126:43379 ::ffff:74.125.224.174:80   CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      1 ::ffff:192.168.1.126:60217 ::ffff:74.125.239.14:443   CLOSE_WAIT
```

Note 97.74.42.79:80 twice.

Guess I'll have to do the same unless someone has a better idea.

Comment: I'm currently working on trying to get this to work. On closer inspection, it is the VpnService that creates the tunnel, not the people who wrote the tPacketCapture.

Answer (score 6):

I have worked with the VPN API. You have a tun device where you can specify the routes. But after having read you need to take care of the packets yourself. Usually that means handing them over to the VPN Server. The Android SDK provides a simple ToyVPNServer Example.

But a simple pcap like interface is difficult (if even possible) to implement without implementing VPN too.

You *could* parse the TCP/UDP header create an own socket with the same src/dest port/ip, use protect() on this socket so it not routed over tun0. Since [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture) only supports udp/tcp and not icmp they might use this approach.

Comment: Indeed, tPacketCapture works using VpnService. Out of curiosity, I've attempted to recreate its functionality, but I'm stuck at what to do with the resulting file descriptor. I obtain a `ParcelFileDescriptor` from `VpnService.Builder.establish()` and wrap it in a `FileInputStream`. Reading the stream simply keeps yielding byte 69, 'E'. I'm trying to figure out how to correctly interface with the file descriptor, but no luck thus far.

Comment: I am not entiliry sure what java does. But in the C world you would just do a read()/write() call and get/write a packet each time.

Comment: I wrote some code out in C, but it, too simply gives me char 'E'. I provided the VPN interface's `getFD()` into a JNI function. In a nutshell what the C code does is: `char buf[1024]; while (long n = read(fd, buf, 1024)) { LOGV("readFd: %s", buf); };`

Comment: that LOGV will stop at the first zero byte. For IPv4 if TOS is 0 (which is very likely) you will have a 0x0 byte there.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma Have you managed to get this working. I'm looking on it to and I would love if you have any code to share

Comment: @StefanRasmusson Yes, but I'm afraid that the code is proprietary.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma I understand, any pointers or good resources that you found along the way?

Comment: @StefanRasmusson Not anything specific. I refreshed my CS bachelor level understanding of TCP, UDP and IP, and stated by writing a Java state machine that handles incoming and outgoing data from the VpnService. I wrote a VPN in Python to run on a Raspberry Pi, and debugged it every step of the way in that fashion. Finally, observing a ton of GCs, I migrated some code to C++ so that I can recycle previous objects instead of constructing new objects for every request.

Comment: @plaisthos: currently facing a similar issue.  I am able to capture the packet in the VpnService, but as you said,  we need to extract the src/dest ip/port from that packet, and handle it. I am struck on that part. If you have been able to solve the problem, please let me know.

Comment: @thedarkpassenger That is "basic" TCP/IP header parsing. Basically you have to implement your own crude tpc/ip stack.

Comment: I'm aware this is an old answer, but for anyone new coming across it with a header parsing issue, you can see my solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51876540/984830