# Android:monitor network traffic using VpnService

Tags: android, vpn, packet-sniffers, network-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to use VpnService implementation to capture and send packets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199553/possible-to-use-vpnservice-implementation-to-capture-and-send-packets)

I have to monitor the network traffic using VpnService. I go through the VpnService example provided at
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ToyVpn/index.html and http://www.taosoftware.co.jp/en/android/packetcapture/
but can't understand that how can i capture the network traffic.Please suggest a way of capturing packets in android or post references to any such resources.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: See also my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199553/possible-to-use-vpnservice-implementation-to-capture-and-send-packets